# Updates in xml file not visible for flash program

Tags: xml, google-chrome, flash

I am a web developer and facing a problem since xml is internally stored in chrome cache. Hence, my updates to the xml file are not seen by my swf flash program.

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a randomly generated number/string or the current time as a GET query string, like:

```
var xmlFile:String = "file.xml?no-cache=" + new Date().time.toString();
trace(xmlFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cache is used for a good reason - it prevents client computer from downloading the same file over and over again. You should not use "cache killers", even though this is an answer you will frequently encounter. Because, by adding a random number to a request sent by GET method you don't prevent your file from being cached - instead, you create a unique cached copy of your file - needlessly bloating the cache on user's PC (and also running the chance of possible duplicate - since random doesn't guaranty no repetitions).

What you should be doing instead:

1. If your data is modified very often (once every couple of hours is often enough), you  should consider sending it with a POST method's response. POST responses aren't generally cached (unless by proxy servers - but that's an entirely different matter).
2. Provide proper cache-control headers. Look up HTTP protocol specification and read about the options you can use. There are multiple possible, they may limit the life of the cache to a certain date, or certain amount of time since the copy was cached and so on.

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/ this is an article I'd advise for further reading.